# aws_elb terraform error failed to load root config module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, terraform

Here's the block of code for aws_elb from main.tf.

```
resource "aws_elb" "terraformelb" {
  name = "terraformelb"
  subnets         = ["${aws_subnet.public_subnet.id}"]
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.web_sg.id}"]
  instances       = ["${aws_instance.web_*.id}"]
  listener {
    instance_port     = 80
    instance_protocol = "http"
    lb_port           = 80
    lb_protocol       = "http"
  }
}
```

I have followed terraform syntax and I still get the error

```
Failed to load root config module: Error loading C:\Users\snadella001\Downloads\Terraform\repo\main.tf: Error reading config for aws_elb[terraform-elb]: parse error at 1:21: expected expression but found "."
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is for resource `terraform-elb` (a minus in the name)

But your resource name is `terraformelb`

You need to make sure the names are same.

Comment: I think my file was not saved earlier. I saved the file and ran terraform plan and still get the same error.

Failed to load root config module: Error loading C:\Users\snadella001\Downloads\Terraform\repo\main.tf: Error reading config for aws_elb[terraformelb]: parse error at 1:21: expected expression but found "."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your instances section is wrong, it should look something like this, I'm guessing (not being able to see the rest of your code):

`instances = ["${aws_instance.web.*.id}"]`